# Tinting Image Processing on Android

Tags: java, android, image-processing

I tried to follow [Image Processing – Tint Color (Yet Another) Tutorial](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/10/18/image-processing-tint-color-yet-another/), but I don't understand some of the code. I know only one thing that the degree effects number of tone colors. Could you please explain it to me?

The following is the code that I don't understand:

```
                int index = y * width + x;
                int r = ( pix[index] >> 16 ) & 0xff;
                int g = ( pix[index] >> 8 ) & 0xff;
                int b = pix[index] & 0xff;
                RY = ( 70 * r - 59 * g - 11 * b ) / 100;
                GY = (-30 * r + 41 * g - 11 * b ) / 100;
                BY = (-30 * r - 59 * g + 89 * b ) / 100;
                Y  = ( 30 * r + 59 * g + 11 * b ) / 100;
                RYY = ( S * BY + C * RY ) / 256;
                BYY = ( C * BY - S * RY ) / 256;
                GYY = (-51 * RYY - 19 * BYY ) / 100;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, this bit of code is changing the color of each of the RBG channels in the image. I'll break it down line by line.

```
            int r = ( pix[index] >> 16 ) & 0xff;
            int g = ( pix[index] >> 8 ) & 0xff;
            int b = pix[index] & 0xff;
```

The bit of code above just gets the native red, blue, and green values.

```
            RY = ( 70 * r - 59 * g - 11 * b ) / 100;
            GY = (-30 * r + 41 * g - 11 * b ) / 100;
            BY = (-30 * r - 59 * g + 89 * b ) / 100;
```

These are fed back in later, but note that RY will be mostly red, BY mostly blue, and GY will be a blend of green and red. One key feature is that all 3 multipliers add up to 0, thus preserving the neutrality of the correction (The image won't get brighter). GY actually doesn't matter, as it is not used anywhere else in the code.

```
            Y  = ( 30 * r + 59 * g + 11 * b ) / 100;
            RYY = ( S * BY + C * RY ) / 256;
            BYY = ( C * BY - S * RY ) / 256;
            GYY = (-51 * RYY - 19 * BYY ) / 100;
```

Again, just applying a formula to get the desired tinting effects. S and C are Sin and Cos values for an angle passed into the function as it is called. The tint is a function of the angle passed. At angle 0, the image will be the closest to normal colors, as the angle is changed, it will tend to change red to blue, blue to red, and green will be some combination of the two, mostly depended on the red.

Comment: really appreciate your explanation ><!! You've made my day :))